# subprocess.run blocking progression of script on windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

So I've been trying to use the CLI of a program that handles licenses (VLC - Vector License Client), by reading the output of a command ("Vector.LicenseClient -listlicenses -DisableLogging -v") which lists said licenses.

My issue:
when I run the following command:

```py
output = subprocess.check_output(self.licensecommand, cwd=self.licensepath, text= True, shell = True)
```

it runs differently on (as far as I'm concerned) two identically set up computers.

On windows computer "A", the command runs in the background, gives output it's stdout and the script finishes correctly.
On windows computer "B", the command opens a new shell (with the name of the command) and runs the command there, asking for confirmation by pressing any button, which pauses and kills the script.
I tried running the command directly in cmd, and in that case it behaved normally on both computers, meaning it simply listed the licenses to the cmd where the command was called.

I tried calling the command without shell, but whatever I did, it could not recognize the command that way.

I also tried killing and timing out the new shell, but it completely blocks the script.

I naturally saw some nice solutions on other posts, but all of those were OS-specific and did not work on Windows. (like os.killpg)

I'm unfortunately not big on Python, and while I'm slowly learning, this is far beyond me.

Comment: What is the command you are trying to call? This will help determine why you would need to run it in shell and how it could be run differently without a shell.

Comment: @ypnos it is a command for VLC (Vector License Client) that goes like:
"Vector.LicenseClient -listlicenses -DisableLogging -v". I'll edit the question too, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean "can only run it with shell set to true"? Unless it checks its PPID, the program doesn't know if you started it from a shell or not (but with `shell=False` you need to pass an _argument list_, not a single string). You need `shell=True` for things that are shell built-ins, but it's _never_ strictly required when the thing you start is an actual executable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am in no way an expert, but I think I tried every possible way to call the command with shell set to false and it could never find the command. With shell set to true it had no problem executing it tho. I tried to pass it as an argument list, and I also tried using shlex.split. I might be doing something wrong, but I did try everything I saw online. Also added to the question description, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you run that command from the command line, without python, do you still need to press enter for it to do something? Or did it finish and exit without user interaction?

Comment: `shlex.split` is Python's _idea_ of what shell parsing is, but it's not real shell parsing, and it's _especially_ not real shell parsing _on Windows_; the `shlex` module follows POSIX rules (and only the subset of those related to quote removal and word splitting), not Windows rules.

Comment: Anyhow -- you'd probably get more answers and less kibitzing/spitballing if you had a [mre] people could run without needing a proprietary tool only you have.

Comment: (_Is_ `Vector.LicenseClient` an executable? If so, where is that executable located? Does that location show up in `os.environ['PATH']`?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll check the enviroment. Naturally I tried it without using shlex as well, I've been trying to solve it for 2 straight days after all. About the reproductability... I did not experience such problems with any other programs or calls. As such it could be a program specific problem. I'm simply hoping that is not the case.

Comment: Did you try this way of calling the command? `output = subprocess.check_output(["Vector.LicenseClient", "-listlicenses", "-DisableLogging", "-v"], cwd=self.licensepath, text=True, timeout=5)`?

Comment: @ypnos I did, but as far as I know shlex split gives the very same list.

Comment: I see, there was just some confusion in the comments whether the command name would be split or something.

Comment: @ypnos, ...my caution against relying on shlex was more general, not so much specific to this individual command. (It definitely does follow POSIX rules, not Windows rules, but the OP's stated command line is simple enough that that shouldn't be biting them right here and now).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I heavily modified my question, do you think it's any better? Should I delete this post and create a new ticket instead?

Comment: @zvone Sorry I just saw your reply, I somehow skipped over it. No, if I run it in cmd, it seems to work normally on both computers.

Comment: That would mean that VLC is behaving differently when you run it from python and when you run it from command line. VLC does not "know" that it is being run from python, so there must be something else which changes its behaviour. Maybe there is some difference in the command line arguments or some difference in environment variables? Or it checks cwd? If you make it see the same environment, it should behave the same in the end.

Comment: The only real problem I have with this question right now is that it doesn't definitively have enough information to let someone else see the problem themselves, which means it doesn't let people test their answers. Have you tried to reach out to Vector support? Their development team would know more about how their software is installed than we do. (It also still would be helpful to answer some of the questions I asked earlier -- where the executable is on your hard drive, and whether that location is in your PATH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem:

Solution for only being able to call command with shell = True:

I could only run the command without shell set to true if I called the full path of the command. Meaning isntead of calling
"command -params" + shell = True
I had to call
"C:\full\path\to\command -params" + shell = False

The solution for the shell pop-up blocking the script:

It was an issue/bug with a certain version of the executable, and/or with the fact that the host PC had a different version installed than the remote PC it worked together with.

Thanks to everyone for the help in the comments.